# Array variable is used before assigned a value

Tags: arrays, vb.net

When I rebuild the solution I get the warning:

> ***"Variable 'aMyArray' is used before it has been assigned a value."***

A function in VB.NET uses an array which is dynamically populated.

*Example:*

```
Function MyArray()
    Try
        Dim aMyArray()
        For i = 0 to 100
            ReDim Preserve aMyArray(i)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

How should I declare a dynamically populated array to eliminate this warning?

Comment: First thing you should do is turn [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) **On**. This will prevent you from creating functions like `Function MyArray() As Surprise`, and functions that should have been a `Sub`. Next I suggest you use a [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). If not: `Dim aMyArray As Object() = New Object(-1){}`.

Comment: I agree 100%, turn Option Strict On, use a List, and also DON'T surround your code with an empty Try-Catch.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, I love `Function MyArray() As Surprise` !!

Comment: @Plutonix Haha! It was either that or `kaboom`. Thumbs up for taking your time to write such a profound answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the CreateInstance to avoid possible errors:

```
Dim aMyArray() as string = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(String),0)
```

Comment: From now on, I suggest you declare and instantiate arrays *the .net way*: `Dim aMyArray As String() = New String(-1) {}`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I do it this way because I do not know the type at design-time. This gives me the ability to pass the TYPE and create an empty array (when needed) at run-time. I am pretty sure that Array.CreateInstance did not exist until .NET

Comment: Say what? If you don't know the type at design-time then you should use `Object`, as shown in my comment. If you still want a strongly-typed array then your only option is generic types like `Function MyArray(Of T)() As T()`. IMHO, this smells like bad design if you have to instantiate your arrays using the `CreateInstance`.

Comment: BTW, by saying *"the .net way"* I mean `Dim aMyArray As String()` as opposed to `Dim aMyArray() As String`.

Comment: @Steve. This is a very interesting solution.  I plan on testing both this and the List collection.  MSDN info on creating arrays under these circumstances is inadequate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

A. Your function returns nothing, so you should also have a warning about that

B. You seriously need to turn on `Option Strict` and let the compiler point out other errors like aMyArray has no Type.

C. Never use and empty `Try/Catch`; if there is an exception, you *want* to know when something goes wrong (and where) so you can fix it.

D. Avoid arrays like the plague.  `ReDim Preserve aMyArray(i)`  creates a new array and then copies all the data to the new structure.  This can be costly in terms of performance if it is a large array of something like strings.  Net has several very nice collections such as `List(of T)` which do not need to be explicitly resized:

```
Private myList As New List(of String)    ' or Integer, Decimal or even MyClassObject
...
myList.Add("Hello")
myList.Add("Lists...")
myList.Add("Goodbye")
myList.Add("Arrays")
```

D(1). The result of using a `List` would mean that entire procedure can be done away with.  Just add new things to the list as needed.

E.  The code posted cant actually result in the warning because you dont ever add a value to it.  Adding: `aMyArray(2) = 2` after the loop *will* result in the warning.  This is because you have never fully declared the array (size and type) as in:

```
Dim aMyArray(100) As String
```

`ReDim` simply resizes the array which isnt the same thing.

F. Since there is nothing in your new array, there is no reason to use `ReDim Preserve` because there is nothing to preserve.  I'll assume that is supposed to be some calculation.  On the other hand, if you *are* trying to resize an existing array, it should be a Sub.

We are all left to guess if it really is meant to modify an existing array (based on `ReDim Preserve`) or return a new array of stuff (considering the array is declared in the procedure).

Again, none of this is needed using a `List`, `Dictionary` or other Collection Type.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I like the idea of using the List collection. The example was not the real code, it was just meant to convey the idea and the problem.  The real code is much more complex.  Like you, I've never liked arrays and try to avoid them.